# Как настроить фильтры в emmet-atom?

Tags: html, css, json, atom

Код который работает в sublime text 3

```
{
  "syntaxProfiles": {
    "html" : {
      "filters" : "html, bem"
    }
  },
  "preferences": {
    "bem.elementSeparator":"__",
    "bem.modifierSeparator":"--",
    "bem.shortElementPrefix":"-"
  }
}
```

Как реализовать такое в atom? Пробовал так, но ничего не происходило.

```
'*':
  'emmet':
    'syntaxProfiles':
      'html':
        'filters': 'html, bem'
```

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что вы хотите переопределить стандартные `__` для элемента и `--` для модификатора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Открываем настройки Emmet: File → Settings → Packages → Emmet.
2. Вставляем в поле Extensions Path полный путь к папке, в которой будет храниться файл *preferences.json*.
3. Создаём в указанной папке файл *preferences.json* следующего содержания:

   ```
   {
     "bem.elementSeparator": "-",
     "bem.modifierSeparator": "--",
     "bem.shortElementPrefix": "---",
   }
   ```

   где вместо дефисов будет то, что вам нужно.
4. Пишем код так `.block>.-el+.-el--mod|bem` и получаем:

   ```
   <div class="block">
     <div class="block-el"></div>
     <div class="block-el--mod"></div>
   </div>
   ```

По умолчанию фильтры определять не нужно и они равняются следующим значениям: `__` элемент, `--` модификатор, `-` префикс, соответственно, запись вида `.block>.__el+.__el--mod|bem` развернется так:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__el"></div>
  <div class="block__el--mod"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: В emmet по умолчанию для элемента `__ ` и для модификатора `_` , да хотел переопределить стандартные на  `--` для модификатора.  `.block>.-el--mod|bem` <div class="block">
    <div class="block__el--mod"></div>
  </div>                                                     `.block>.-el--mod|bem`           <div class="block">
    <div class="block__el block__el--mod"></div>
  </div>

Comment: У модификатора `--` и так по умолчанию, код в ответе копипастил из собственного редактора )

Comment: А как фильтр добавить? чтоб не приходилось постоянно дописывать вертикальную черту бэм `|bem`, я правда до этого так делал, напрямую файл находил и там изменял) только после этого ctrl+u для изображений не работало.

Comment: А вот этого не знаю, я сам всегда `|bem` пишу.

Comment: https://docs.emmet.io/filters/bem/ там по умолчанию от `_` яндекса модификатор стоит)

Comment: Сделал по твоему варианту) создал `syntaxProfiles.json` и написал `{
  "html" : {
    "filters" : "html, bem"
  }
}` все работает.